# What kind of images are used in iphone?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i am making a game with a background and animated helicopter that is flying.When i see other iphone games their backgrounds are so graphically strong ,mine is not near to that .Why is that?

Are there any special type of images used in iphone?

Comment: Could you describe "graphically strong" in more detail please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPG, PNG, BMP, etc are all capable of being displayed fine on an iPhone.

Keep an eye out for:

- If you are resizing the image (in either direction), it may lose detail.
- If you are not using the full bit-depth - e.g. if you are only using 16 colours.
- If you are highly compressing JPEG images, which is a lossy format.

Of course, if your source image looks bad, it will continue to look bad.

Comment: In other words, the other developers have artists or are artists :)